# Pass unassigned variables in a function Python

Tags: python, function

Is is possible to pass a list of unassigned variables through a function? In df_name, I want to pass the names of the dataframes I want.

In this function, I am scraping song links from genius api. I have 3 links that I am scraping from. And After each link is scraped, I want to assign it to the variable name under df_name

```
def getalbumlyrics(urllinks, df_name):
    for i, albumurl in enumerate(urllinks):
        res = requests.get(albumurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        track_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'chart_row-content'})
        songs = []
        for track in track_list:
            album = {}
            song = track.find('h3').text.strip().split('\n').pop(0)
            album['song']= song.replace('\xa0', '')
            songs.append(album)
            album['link'] = track.find('a').attrs['href']

            artist_songlinks = pd.DataFrame(songs)

getalbumlyrics(['https://genius.com/albums/Post-malone/Hollywoods-bleeding',
               'https://genius.com/albums/Billie-eilish/When-we-all-fall-asleep-where-do-we-go',
               'https://genius.com/albums/Ariana-grande/Thank-u-next'],
              [post, billie, ariana])
```

I get an error: `NameError: name 'post' is not defined`

Comment: Why not just return the song links from the function, then do `[post, billie, ariana] = getalbumlyrics(. . .`? Even if you could do what you wanted to do (I don't think you can), just returning would be much cleaner.

Comment: Python is a pass-by-value language. Passing a variable to a function won't allow the function to update the caller's variable.

Comment: There **is no such thing as an unassigned variable in Python**.

Comment: @Barmar to be pendantic, Python does not use call-by-value semantics, it uses call-by-object-sharing. Of course, it *certainly* doesn't use call-by-reference. But it is distinct from both of those.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's call-by-value, and the value is an object reference.

Comment: @Barmar no, it isn't. That's just mixing up implementation details with evaluation strategy semantics. You could say the same thing about call-by-reference, since indeed, it can be implemented using call by value where the value is a reference. In Python, there are objects and names. When an object is passed to a function, it is isn't call by value because the object is never copied. It isn't call by reference because assignment to the parameter does not affect the caller.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what I meant by "the value is an object reference". The reference is copied, the object isn't. I'm using the traditional meaning of "call by referfence" as in Fortran, Algol `out` parameters, etc.

Comment: @Barmar right, I'm not saying it's call by reference. I'm stating it is *neither* call by value nor call by reference. I know what you meant, but the evaluation strategy Python employs is really neither, the fact that the object reference is copied in CPython is an *implementation detail* that does not affect the semantics of python's evaluation strategy. My point is simply that I could say the same thing. For example, I could implement a language in C and implement call by reference semantics, but that wouldn't make the semantics call by value because I'm using C to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, it's probably best to rewrite some aspects of your code. 
1) Change `getalbumlyrics` to take a single url: `getalbumlyrics(urllink)`
2) Return `artist_songlinks` for that url.

This simplifies your code to:

```
def getalbumlyrics(urllink):
    res = requests.get(urllink)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    track_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'chart_row-content'})
    songs = []
    for track in track_list:
        album = {}
        song = track.find('h3').text.strip().split('\n').pop(0)
        album['song']= song.replace('\xa0', '')
        songs.append(album)
        album['link'] = track.find('a').attrs['href']

    artist_songlinks = pd.DataFrame(songs)

    return artist_songlinks
```

Then you can decide how you want to maintain the result.

```
# You could call the function directly for each artist
post = getalbumlyrics('https://genius.com/albums/Post-malone/Hollywoods-bleeding')
billie = getalbumlyrics('https://genius.com/albums/Billie-eilish/When-we-all-fall-asleep-where-do-we-go')
ariana = getalbumlyrics('https://genius.com/albums/Ariana-grande/Thank-u-next')

# Or loop
artists = {
   "post": {
       "url": "https://genius.com/albums/Post-malone/Hollywoods-bleeding",
       "result": None
   }
   "billie": {
       "url": "https://genius.com/albums/Billie-eilish/When-we-all-fall-asleep-where-do-we-go",
       "result": None
   }
   "ariana": {
       "url": "https://genius.com/albums/Ariana-grande/Thank-u-next",
       "result": None
   }
}

for artist, data in artists.iteritems():
    data["result"] = getalbumlyrics(data["url"])

# Example
print(artists["post"]["result"])
```

Comment: I will note though that this definitely isn't the cleanest way to do it. Ideally you can tie each returned dataframe to the url that was used to generate it.

Comment: I don't follow this at all

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest, most Pythonic, is return a list of results, one for each link.  That is, you provide a list of links, and get back a list of results.

```
def getalbumlyrics(urllinks):
    results = []    # collect return values in this list
    for i, albumurl in enumerate(urllinks):
        res = requests.get(albumurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        track_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'chart_row-content'})
        songs = []
        for track in track_list:
            album = {}
            song = track.find('h3').text.strip().split('\n').pop(0)
            album['song']= song.replace('\xa0', '')
            songs.append(album)
            album['link'] = track.find('a').attrs['href']

        artist_songlinks = pd.DataFrame(songs)
        results.append(artist_songlinks)   # or whatever the desire result is
    return results
```

Call the function with the list of links, and get back a list.  You can then unpack that list to your variables, if that's convenient.  Or keep the list, or repackage the results into a dictionary.

```
links = ['https://genius.com/albums/Post-malone/Hollywoods-bleeding',
               'https://genius.com/albums/Billie-eilish/When-we-all-fall-asleep-where-do-we-go',
               'https://genius.com/albums/Ariana-grande/Thank-u-next']
results = getalbumlyrics(links)
post, billie, ariana = results    # only works for 3 links
```

This unpacking locks you into passing just 3 links, in a specific order.  If you want to add another link, you have to change `links` and the unpacking.  If you don't try to assign results to explicit variable names, you can easily change the number of links, without changing the code.